# Get sales info from SOAP API magento

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

How to get SKU,Customer address of the products ordered in salesOrderList API

Comment: You need to customize salesOrderList API method

Comment: you can check default request and response parameter [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html)

Comment: how to add salesOrderAddressEntity  and salesOrderItemEntity  in salesOrderList

Comment: over write or rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php function items().change wsdl and wsi file for complexType salesOrderListEntity and change response as you need